# Python-Django Multiple Database - TypeError: allow_migrate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'app_label' Error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So I'm working creating a multiple database assign in my django framework setup. And this documentation i'm following https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/multi-db/ .

But when i try run it i encounter some error in my database router.

```
TypeError: allow_migrate() missing one required positional argument : 'app_label'
```

These error occurs in my AuthRouter.py and PrimaryReplicaRouter.py

Below is my AuthRouter.py and PrimaryReplicaRouter.py code

AuthRouter.py code

```
class AuthRouter:

def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
    if model._meta.app_label == 'auth':
        return 'auth_db'
    return None

def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
    if model._meta.app_label == 'auth':
        return 'auth_db'
    return None

def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
    if obj1._meta.app_label == 'auth' or \
       obj2._meta.app_label == 'auth':
       return True
    return None

def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
    if app_label == 'auth':
        return db == 'auth_db'
    return None
```

PrimaryReplicaRouter.py Code

```
import random

class PrimaryReplicaRouter:

def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
    return random.choice(['db1', 'db2'])

def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
    return 'primarydb'

def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
    db_list = ('primarydb', 'db1', 'db2')
    if obj1._state.db in db_list and obj2._state.db in db_list:
        return True
    return None

def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
    """
    All non-auth models end up in this pool.
    """
    return True
```

Does anyone here also encounter this kind of problem?

Thank you all for help. :)

Comment: Show us the code for your router? Presumably your method definition for `allow_migrate()` is not what it should be.

Comment: @solarissmoke hey man i just update my question and attached there my code for routers. So yes i just copy the code for routers in the django documentation and just replace the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@staticmethod
def allow_migrate(db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
    """
    All non-auth models end up in this pool.
    """
    return True
```

You should have decorator `@staticmethod` for other functions as well.